# Rails: Signing out user from both desktop site and mobile API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, spree

This Rails project uses Spree and Devise and has a separate controller to serve up JSON responses for the mobile side of things. I've just implemented Devise::Lockable to lock a user account after 5 failed logins. This automatically generates a password reset email. Things work fine on the desktop site and on the mobile site. My question comes from mixing the two together:

If you fail login 5 times through mobile API, the password link is sent to that account's email. But if you are already signed in on the desktop, and then also access the reset link from the desktop, it redirects to the home page (and signs out the user). If you click the reset link again, then the password reset form is served up.

How can I also sign out a user on from "normal" app (the desktop side of things) when the user fails logging in the maximum times on the mobile app?

EDIT: I've tried throwing Devise's "sign_out user" at almost every point in the pipeline but that doesn't do the trick, since the user for some reason isn't found to be signed in.